# Applying accordion with div having data-attribute as title

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I got a structure like this... to display the title before the div with data-attribute.

I want to make it like

1st Title

2nd Title

3rd Title

4th Title

-> Click "1st Title", it becomes

1st Title

*First Content*

2nd Title

3rd Title

4th Title

So I want to ask is there any ways that I can apply this accordion on it without changing the html structure (Having ul,li first then show the div)?

```css
ul {
  display:none;
  }

div:before {
  content:attr(data-title);
  display:block;
  font-size:14px;
  background:gray;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:14px
  }
  
div {
  background:lightgray;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="first">1st Header</li>
    <li id="second">2nd Header</li>
    <li id="third">3rd Header</li>
    <li id="fourth">4th header</li>
</ul>
<div id="first_div" data-title="1st Header title">First content <br/>1111111111111111111111</div>
<div id="second_div" data-title="2nd Header title">Second content <br/>22222222222222222222</div>
<div id="third_div" data-title="3rd Header title">Third content <br/>33333333333333333333</div>
<div id="fourth_div" data-title="4th Header title">Fourth content <br/>4444444444444444444</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('li').click(function(){
  if($(this).find('div.content').length == 0){
    $(this).append('<div class="content">' + $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_div').html() + '</div>');
    $('li').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('div.content').length != 0)
      $(this).find('div.content').slideUp();
    });
    $(this).find('div.content').slideDown();
  } else {
    if($(this).find('div.content').css('display') == 'block'){
      $(this).find('div.content').slideUp();
    } else {
      $(this).find('div.content').slideDown();
    }
  }
  
});
```

```css
li {
 list-style: none;
}

div:before {
  content:attr(data-title);
  display:block;
  font-size:14px;
  background:gray;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:14px
  }
  
div {
  background:lightgray;
  }
  
.content{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="first">1st Header</li>
  <li id="second">2nd Header</li>
  <li id="third">3rd Header</li>
  <li id="fourth">4th header</li>
</ul>
<div class="content" id="first_div" data-title="1st Header title">First content <br/>1111111111111111111111</div>
<div class="content" id="second_div" data-title="2nd Header title">Second content <br/>22222222222222222222</div>
<div class="content" id="third_div" data-title="3rd Header title">Third content <br/>33333333333333333333</div>
<div class="content" id="fourth_div" data-title="4th Header title">Fourth content <br/>4444444444444444444</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I don't know why the click function is not functioning on my html... Anyway I think you have given me a good reference on it...Thank you!

Comment: @Sammi Welcome buddy :)

Comment: Sorry can I ask you one more question on it? So I can see from the css, in div:before there is a line with "content:attr(data-title)", but from your snippet result I can see you are actually getting the content inside the <li>.... Can you explain a bit about this? I am trying your code but I cannot make my title display in your way! @Shiladitya