# Having accordion on div after each li

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

So I have asked a question yesterday: [Applying Accordion with div having data-attribute as title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404940/applying-accordion-with-div-having-data-attribute-as-title/47405288?noredirect=1#comment81770494_47405288)

But I found that this is not the desired method using data-attr as I cannot use it as a selector in jQuery when I want to make a toggle with it.

I got a structure like this... to display the title before the div.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

div {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="first">1st Title</li>
  <li id="second">2nd Title</li>
  <li id="third">3rd Title</li>
  <li id="fourth">4th Title</li>
</ul>
<div id="first_div">First content <br/>1111111111111111111111</div>
<div id="second_div">Second content <br/>22222222222222222222</div>
<div id="third_div">Third content <br/>33333333333333333333</div>
<div id="fourth_div">Fourth content <br/>4444444444444444444</div>
```

I want to make it like

```
1st Title

2nd Title

3rd Title

4th Title
```

-> Click "1st Title", it becomes

```
1st Title

First Content

2nd Title

3rd Title

4th Title
```

And similar when clicking the other titles
Without changing the html structure (ul li come first and div after)

Can anyone provide me some solution as I have already struggling with this one for days... would like to know how to solve it! Thanks!

Comment: show in html what your desired output  structure should be

Comment: previous question is similar this might be closed as duplicate

Comment: @sammi, what have you tried in javascript-jquery?

Comment: @guradio the result I want is similar but I want to make it without data-attr, but just use the li as title

Comment: @SudarpoChong Can you take a look in my previous post, it is hard to post in this comment! But I am trying to make it without data-attr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying accordion with div having data-attribute as title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404940/applying-accordion-with-div-having-data-attribute-as-title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```js
$("li").on("click", function(e) {
  
  $("li").not(this).removeClass("has-content");
 $("li").not(this).find(".extra").remove();
  
  // console.log("ID", $(this).attr("id"));
  var div_id = "#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_div";
  
  var div_content = $(div_id).html();
  // console.log(div_content);
  if (!$(this).hasClass("has-content")) {
    $(this)
      .addClass("has-content")
      .append("<div class='extra'>" + div_content + "</div>");  
  }
  else {
   $(this).removeClass("has-content");
  $(this).find(".extra").remove();
  }
  
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #ff0;
}

div {
  background: lightgray;
  display: none;
}

div.extra {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="first">1st Title</li>
  <li id="second">2nd Title</li>
  <li id="third">3rd Title</li>
  <li id="fourth">4th Title</li>
</ul>
<div id="first_div">First content <br/>1111111111111111111111</div>
<div id="second_div">Second content <br/>22222222222222222222</div>
<div id="third_div">Third content <br/>33333333333333333333</div>
<div id="fourth_div">Fourth content <br/>4444444444444444444</div>
```

Comment: I have tried with your code, but the content in div is always affected bu the styling of li, like if my title background-color is red, when I clicked on it, the content background will also become red. How can I set the styling for the content part such that it is not affected?

Comment: you can assign separate background color to content part?

Comment: Yes, ok thanks! And I want to ask if I want to content to be hidden at first, I set "display:none"...but then it cant be shown when I click on the title...do you have any hints on that? Thanks!

Comment: @Sammi can modify anything on html ? like add class, etc?